# How do I translate the loop part of Common Lisp code into Clojure? ... functional orientation

Tags: loops, clojure, functional-programming, lisp

How do I translate the loop part of this working Common Lisp (SBCL v.1.2.3) code into Clojure (v.1.6)? I am a bit frustrated after working on it for some hours/days without results. Somewhere I don't get this functional orientation I suppose ...

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Unconditional Entropy
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;; Probabilities
(setq list_occur_prob '()) ;; init

;; set probabilities for which we want to calculate the entropy
(setq list_occur_prob '(1/2 1/3 1/6)) ;;

;; Function to calculate the unconditional
;; entropy H = -sigma i=0,n (pi*log2(pi)
;; bits persymbol.
(setq entropy 0) ;; init
(setq entropy (loop for i in list_occur_prob
   for y = (* (log_base2 i) i)
     collect y
                 ))
(setq entropy (* -1 (apply '+ entropy))) ;; change the sign

;; Print the unconditional entropy in bits per symbol.
(print entropy) ;; BTW, here the entropy is 1.4591479 bits per symbol.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They key operation you need is `map` which transforms a sequence using a function. 
In the entropy example you gave, the following should work:

```
(def probabilities [1/2 1/3 1/6]) 

(defn log [base x]
  (/ (Math/log x) (Math/log base))) 

(defn entropy [probabilities]
    (->> probabilities
         (map #(* (log 2 %) %)) ; note  - #(f %) is shorthand for (fn [x] (f x))
         (reduce +)
         (-))) 

(entropy probabilities)  ; => 1.459
```

When working with collections, the pipeline operator (`->>`) is often used 
to clearly show a sequence of operations. I personally find it much easier to read than the nested bracket syntax, especially if there are lots of operations.

Here, we're first mapping the `pi * log2(pi)` function over the sequence, 
and then summing it using `(reduce +)`

Answer (score 5):

Before we dive into the Clojure equivalent of the code, you should take some time to clean up the Common Lisp code. Using `setq`the way you're doing it is considered bad style at best and can lead to undefined consequences at worst: `setq` is intended to assign values to variables, but your variables `list_occur_prob`and `entropy` aren't defined (via `defvar`). In addition, this piece of code looks like you're assigning global variables (cf. [`defvar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm#defvar) again), which are dynamic variables, which by convention should be marked with earmuffs, e.g. `*entropy*.`

However, for this small piece of code, you could just as well use local, non-dynamic variables, introduced via `let` like this (warning, I don't have any CL or Clojure environment handy):

```
 (let ((list_occur_prob '(1/2 1/3 1/6)))
   (loop for i in list_occur_prob
         for y = (* (log_base 2 i) i)
         collect y into acc
         finally (return (* -1 (apply '+ acc)))))
```

There are ways to optimize the `apply` clause away into the loop:

```
(let ((list-occur-prob '(1/2 1/3 1/6)))
  (- (loop for i in list-occur-prob
           sum (* (log i 2) i))))
```

Now, Daniel Neal has shown you already a map/reduce based solution, here is one which is more closer to the original looping construct, using a recursive approach:

```
 (defn ent-helper [probs acc]
    (if (seq probs)
        (recur (rest probs) 
               (conj acc (* (log_base 2 (first probs)) (first probs))))
        acc))

 (let [probs 1/2 1/3 1/6
       acc (ent-helper probs [])] 
    (* -1 (apply +  acc))
```

We're using `conj` instead of `collect` to gather the results into the accumulator. The call to `ent-helper`, which is essentially triggered for all values of `probs` via the `recur` recursion call, takes an (initially empty) second parameter in which the values build up so far are collected. If we've exhausted all probabilities, we simply return the collected values.

Again, summing up the values so far could be optimized into the loop, instead of mapping over the values.

Answer (score 4):

I would start with more *functional* Common Lisp code:

```
(- (reduce #'+
           '(1/2 1/3 1/6)
           :key (lambda (i)
                  (* (log i 2) i))))
```

You *can* write imperative code in Lisp, with lots of operations setting variable values, but it is not the best style.

Even a tight `LOOP` can look okay:

```
(- (loop for i in '(1/2 1/3 1/6)
         sum (* (log i 2) i)))
```

Comment: As a bonus, a functionalised version of the code is not only much shorter, but also much easier to translate into Clojure.

Answer (score 2):

I endorse the general flavor of [schaueho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27505412/625403), but if you prefer you can get something closer to the "feel" of the looping approach with Clojure's `for` macro:

```
(apply - 0
       (for [prob [1/2 1/3 1/6]]
         (* (log prob 2) prob)))
```

I find this much easier to read than schaueho's version with manual recursion, and it also performs much better, in that it doesn't traverse the list twice, doesn't accumulate results into a temporary vector, and so on.

Note that `(- (apply + xs))` is the same as `(apply - 0 xs)`, although which one you find clearer is probably a matter of taste. Also, I'm assuming you already have a suitable `log` function defined elsewhere.